# How the short type is represented by the Visual C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, short, representation

I know that most significant bit means the sign of a number in signed types. But I found one strange (for me) thing: if the number is negative and we use short type, this number will look like `0xffff####`. How can this be? Short contains only 2 bytes and in `0xffff####` we see 4 whole bytes. Why do 16 more bits become one in binary representation. Explain me, please, how does it works.

For example,

```
short s = 0x8008;
printf("%x", s);

Output:
>>> ffff8008
```

Comment: Calling a function with a variadic argument list promotes integer types that are smaller than `int` to `int`.

Comment: [Documentation link for above explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)

Comment: @PeteBecker, thanks a lot. I spend an hour to find the answer and the the answer was so simle.

Comment: Use "%hx" instead.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097654/12002570) explains this. Here is another dupe: [Why is compiler converting char to int in printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163712/why-is-compiler-converting-char-to-int-in-printf).

Answer (score 1):

As @Pete Becker says, the problem is implicit conversion to `int`. If you try the same thing with C++ iostreams you will get the output you expect though

```
#include <iostream>

int main() { 

    short foo = 0x8008;
    std::cout << std::hex << foo << "\n";

    short bar = -32760;
    std::cout << std::hex << bar << "\n";

}
```